# Sorting list with strings & ints in numerical order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently dealing with the below list:

```
[['John', '1', '2', '3'], ['Doe', '1', '2', '3']]
```

I'm incredibly new to python, I'm wanting to order this list in numerical order (high - low) but maintain the string at the beginning of the list. Like this:-

```
[['John', '3', '2', '1'], ['Doe', '3', '2', '1']]
```

There will always be one name & integers there after.

I collect this list from a csv file like so:-

```
import csv

with open('myCSV.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)

print(sorted(your_list))
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance..

Comment: There are no integers in that list anywhere, only (lists of) strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the list and sort only the slice of each sublist without the first item. To sort strings as numbers pass `key=int` to sorted. Use `reverse=True` since you need a reversed order:

```
>>> l = [['John', '1', '2', '3'], ['Doe', '1', '2', '3']]
>>>
>>> [[sublist[0]] + sorted(sublist[1:], key=int, reverse=True) for sublist in l]
[['John', '3', '2', '1'], ['Doe', '3', '2', '1']]
```

Comment: Changing `[sublist[0]]` to `sublist[:1]` would look nicer.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will accept the answer when it lets me.